# Why is "this" question physics, but "that" question is not?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, close

While I think this question

[On the definition of positive linear supermaps on Hilbert spaces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743234/)

may be an interesting mathematical question about Hilbert spaces, why is it not closed for belonging instead to *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* as this question,

[Cooling of 2 hot fluid streams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743143/)

was closed for belonging to engineering, not to *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

Comment: Closing takes time.  While the 2nd is clearly engineering, the first could go either way.  You have VtC privileges so why not VtC as a math question if you think it is?

Comment: Seconding ZeroTheHero's comment, the question that is not closed is only an *hour* old. The typical time it takes for a question to go through the close review queue is *much* longer than that. The closed/open status of (or even the votes on) such a recent question, especially during a time of low activity (Christmas/end-of-year holidays in many places), don't really say anything about what the community thinks about the question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero because I would not close either and usually prefer to defer to my elders... More importantly, I was not arguing either way, just wanted to know.

Comment: @hyportnex you have been a member for 9 years 2 months now; by comparison I have been member for 9 years and 4 months.  You are as much of an "elder" as I am.

Comment: Re *"belonging to engineering"*: Do you mean the Stack Exchange site *[Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

Comment: Likely because someone who got lucky with a 1000+ point answer 10 years ago says so.